# Meteor - How to correctly route inside Template event function

Tags: javascript, templates, events, meteor, iron-router

I have a base template:

```
<template name="ApplicationLayout">
    {{> yield}}
</template>
```

and I route templates into it using Iron Router, like so:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout',
  notFoundTemplate: 'home'
});
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');
});
```

Whenever someone arrives at the site, they'll always be shown the `agegate` template. Once they click the submit button, I want to change to a different page (home).

```
Template.agegate.events({
    "click #submit": function (event) {
        this.render('home');
    }
});
```

The routing actually works (I get to the desired page), but it throws an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I'm assuming this is because the `this` in `this.render('home')` refers to the current template, whereas it needs to refer to the parent template (the `ApplicationLayout` template). However I don't know how to do that, or if that's even relevant.

**So, how to can I correctly route inside a Template event function?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `Router.go('/')`, this should suffice

Comment: Wow, I didn't know how I missed that... Thanks a lot. I tried EVERYTHING but that! =.=

Comment: ummm, but does Router.go do a full page refresh? or is client-side routing optional?